# Highlighting an Ace Editor from outside

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Hi I'm using Ace Editor to enhance an SQL Editor of a Web-interface of a database.

What I'm asking is if it's possible to highlight a specific line or word in the text content of the editor.

For example, I write some sql there, execute the query, and highlight a line based on an error/warning line that I get in the results when an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session.addMarker to add background to a range